# Upper leg bends inside lower leg

Tags: rigging

I have a problem with the knee, it doesn't bend smoothly, it's just getting inside each other, please help, I was struggling with it the whole day, I managed to do the hand but the leg is a lot harder.

Thanks for your attention!

P.S. Fist time asking help :)

[image: knee]

Answer (score 0):

For this you may want to subdivide the object, *then* make it a softbody. When animated, the softbody will collide with itself (with the right settings), and it won't look as weird. Make sure you check the *Self collision* box so that it does collide with itself.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was really helpful for my experience with blender but problem still not solved, it's like you said "With right settings" but this is the first time I met with Physics in blender!